# how to spool object creation into log file

Tags: sql, oracle, shell

I have created a shell script where in i am executing the    Alter_t_new.sql which has all the create and alter table scripts. Now i want whatever errors out or gets created shoul be spooled into the log file. I tried  SPOOL $LOGFILE but that is throwing an error

```
   SPOOL: command not found
```

shell script:

```
echo "Starting installation of XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS ..."
echo "Starting installation of XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS ..."    "">>$LOGFILE
echo   "">>$LOGFILE

echo   "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Copying Files To Appropriate Directories ..."
echo "Copying Files To Appropriate Directories ..."  "">>$LOGFILE


echo   "">>$LOGFILE


echo   "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Files copied successfully !!! "
echo "Files copied successfully !!! "    "">>$LOGFILE
echo   "">>$LOGFILE

echo "Changing permissions ... "     "">>$LOGFILE
chmod 777 *.*
echo "Changed permissions ... "     "">>$LOGFILE

echo    "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Creating Custom Package, Synonyms and Grants..."   "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Creating Custom Package, Synonyms and Grants..."
echo    "">>$LOGFILE

if sqlplus $APPS_USER @Alter_t_new.sql
then
SPOOL $LOGFILE
    echo "Custom itables created successfully in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Custom itables created successfully in APPS schema" 
     SPOOL OFF
else
    echo "Error in creating custom  itables in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Error in creating Custom itables  in APPS schema" 
fi

echo    "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Package, Synonyms,grants and Tables created successfully"   "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Package, Synonyms,grants and Tables created successfully"
echo  "">>$LOGFILE


echo "Installation completed for XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS"
echo "Installation completed for XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS"     "">>$LOGFILE
# *****************************************************************************
# End of Script
# *****************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `SPOOL` command inside your script, it's SQLPlus command. For example file content is:

```
SPOOL my_log.log
CREATE TABLE t1
  (col1 NUMBER);
SPOOL OFF
```

You can also use `SET TERMOUT OFF` command to suppress output.

> The TERMOUT setting controls whether SQL*Plus displays output generated by SQL statements, PL/SQL blocks, and SQL*Plus commands. This setting applies only when SQL*Plus is executing a script file. SQL*Plus displays output from commands entered interactively.

Comment: @hinotf- will i have to create my_log in server ?

Comment: @sreekembose log file created where SQLPlus is running

Answer (score 1):

I believe that SPOOL will need to be in the Alter_t_new.sql file. 
I would do something like this:

```
    (from .sh script)
    if sqlplus $APPS_USER @Alter_t_new.sql $LOGFILE
    then
        echo "Custom itables created successfully in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
        echo "Custom itables created successfully in APPS schema" 
         SPOOL OFF
    else
        echo "Error in creating custom  itables in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
        echo "Error in creating Custom itables  in APPS schema" 
    fi


    (from Alter_t_new.sql)
    WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE

    spool &1 APPEND
```

Passing the $LOGFILE as an argument to the sqlplus command

```
sqlplus $APPS_USER @Alter_t_new.sql $LOGFILE
```

and using that argument to append to the log file that you're adding to

```
spool &1 APPEND
```

Also, the WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE bit should return the error to the .sh that called it. Here is some info on WHENEVER SQLERROR: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm

I hope that this helps.